# Worklight SSL errors using local Liberty server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-server

I have the PushAdapter from the example push notification defined in an new project, and, I've added the apns-certificate-sandbox.p12 to the native api application (a native api), added the correct bundleId value in the application-descriptor.xml, but, I keep getting this error:

```
[WARNING ] Failed to retreive invalid devices
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
[ERROR   ] Couldn't get feedback connection
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
[ERROR   ] Unknown exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
Unknown exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
```

This is a new installation of Worklight (6.0.0.20130909-1459), and I've tried two separate installations (one into Eclipse and one into RAD), both same errors.

Is there some additional work that needs to be done for push testing to work in the Worklight Development Server (Websphere Liberty) environment for SSL to work?  There aren't any devices subscribed yet, but, not sure why this error is occurring or if it's relevant at all.

The detailed trace is here:

```
[11/1/13 11:50:20:834 EDT] 00000034 com.worklight.core.exceptions.InstrumentedException          E Unknown exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
com.worklight.core.exceptions.InstrumentedException: Unknown exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
    at com.worklight.core.exceptions.DefaultExceptionHandler.handleException(DefaultExceptionHandler.java:56)
    at com.worklight.core.tasks.TaskThread.run(TaskThread.java:113)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.Utilities.parseFeedbackStreamRaw(Utilities.java:201)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.Utilities.parseFeedbackStream(Utilities.java:211)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsFeedbackConnection.getInactiveDevicesImpl(ApnsFeedbackConnection.java:87)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsFeedbackConnection.getInactiveDevices(ApnsFeedbackConnection.java:67)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.AbstractApnsService.getInactiveDevices(AbstractApnsService.java:99)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsServiceImpl.getInactiveDevices(ApnsServiceImpl.java:36)
    at com.worklight.integration.notification.apns.ApplicationConnection.getInactiveDevices(ApplicationConnection.java:110)
    at com.worklight.integration.notification.apns.APNSMediator.maintain(APNSMediator.java:95)
    at com.worklight.integration.notification.Dispatcher.maintain(Dispatcher.java:148)
    at com.worklight.integration.notification.NotificationCleanupTask.step(NotificationCleanupTask.java:29)
    at com.worklight.core.tasks.TaskThread.run(TaskThread.java:111)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1961)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1077)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:882)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:102)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:69)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:387)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.Utilities.parseFeedbackStreamRaw(Utilities.java:192)
    ... 10 more
```

Comment: I've found the answer to this, but, I can't mark this as the answer.  It scares me a little that no one answered this.  The issue is that Java 1.7 cannot processes p12 certificates differently than 1.6, and, Worklight uses the open source Java PNS (http://code.google.com/p/javapns) to send Apple push notifications.

Comment: (continuing!!)   I don't see any workarounds in using a p12, but, James Low does provide some info in his blog (http://jameslow.com/2013/04/24/iphone-push-notifications-with-javapns-on-google-app-engine/), but, this requires changing from p12 to JKS, which, can't be done with Worklight since this is "baked" in.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like an error from the server trying to test a connection to the Apple Push/Feedback service.

A couple of things to check:

1. Is the application built for development or distribution?
2. If development, ensure you are using the Development SSL certificate.  Export both the certificate and private key into a file named:  apns-certificate-sandbox.p12
3. If distribution, ensure you are using the Production SSL certificate.  Export both the certificate and private key into the a file named: apns-certificate-production.p12
4. Ensure the .p12 file was created correctly and that you specified the corresponding password in the application descriptor file.
5. Ensure that your Worklight server can access the APNs hosts/ports for the push and for feedback service.   i.e Firewall ports need to be opened for the following:

   - gateway.push.apple.com, port 2195
   - gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com, port 2195
   - feedback.push.apple.com, port 2196
   - feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com on port 2196

Comment: We're still getting this error, even with notifications working on Worklight server, using the Apple notifications only.  Errors:  com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsFeedbackConnection getInactiveDevices Failed to retreive invalid devices,                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_revoked... also,  com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsFeedbackConnection.getInactiveDevicesImpl.  Process is run hourly, our notifications are working.  What is this process? Can someone point me to the doc on this?  WAS 8.0.0.6, JDK 1.6.

Comment: David, that looks like a different error... Note it says 'certificate_revoked' instead of 'certificate_unknown', which sounds like Apple revoked your cert.  I don't know why notifications would continue to work though.  Have you tried obtaining/generating a new SSL certificate?

Comment: My notifications are working perfectly.  The error only occurs during this hourly process.  So, my question isn't really what the error is (although I'd be curious to know), but rather what is the Worklight server process that looks like it's checking the notification data in Worklight on an hourly basis?  I don't see it documented anywhere.

Comment: Not sure.  But my guess is that it is querying the Apple feedback service for information about disconnected devices, or errors delivering notifications.  Apple's feedback service is documented here:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW3

Answer (score 1):

Worklight product never used http://code.google.com/p/javapns for push, it is using com.notnoop.apns . This package works well with Oracle JDK 1.6 and 1.7
Can you shed some more light on which JDK exactly version were you using ? 
I tested push sample on the embedded Liberty+Oracle JDK 1.7_07b +iPhone 5 and it worked.
how did you create this certificate ? can you write here step-by-step what you did? (and specify every file you copied,edited i the way)

If you are asking about using javaPNS: Ofcourse, since its an open framework, you could manually copy (and use) any jar into your Worklight project as a 3rd party dependency, however, it seems that this javaPNS jar has some bugs with SSL.

Why don't you look at the Worklight's push notification samples and work your way from there ( http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#client-basics ) ? (Worklight comes with a working push notification solution , works on JDK1.6 or 1.7 without issues with your PKCS12 certificates)

Comment: Sorry, I assumed the com.notnoop.apns is part of javapns, my bad ;-).   My tests are using the sample code provided with Worklight.  It fails working with 1.7 on my machine (Mac OSX).  It works when I switch to use 1.6.  This obviously has nothing to do with ports, certificates, or project configuration.

Answer (score 0):

On my side it has been veririfed that in OS X (sometimes in Windows too actually), the certificate_unknown error is thrown when using JRE 7 instead of JRE 6. It seems that the `notnoop` open source library used in Worklight is not handling well Java 7.

https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns/issues/54